# sql- how to combine select columns, count and comparison in one query?

Tags: sql

By using SQL command, list down idworker,nameworker from worker table and total_late for workers who have 'late' record more than 1 time only.

Comment: It's impossible to answer a question like that. Please share your tables' structures, some sample data and the result you're trying to get for that sample.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: [edit] your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [_Formatted_](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) **text** please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 0):

Try this (assumes there is Late table where there is one record for each occurrence when worker is late):

```
SELECT w.idworker, w.nameworker, l.total_late
FROM Worker w LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT idworker, SUM(late) as total_late, COUNT(*) AS number_late 
 FROM Late GROUP BY idworker) l ON w.idworker = l.idworker
WHERE number_late > 1
```